# How can i block my testing domain for search engine

Tags: php, web-development, wordpress

How can I block this site, that I administer (http://test.puttinout.com/), for search engines?

As I have noticed, Google has indexed most of our pages, but we don't need that Google indexes those pages for us.

Check [Google index details here](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=cr&ei=OGbmUqjGF8bVtQbu_4CQDA#q=site:http://test.puttinout.com/).

Comment: Please any one tell me how can i blocked this through robots.txt ? what whould be write on robots.txt file?

Answer (score 3):

Add a robots.txt file to your root directory. So, create a text file, called Robots.txt with the following information inside (this will block everything):

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Then, upload this file to the website's root directory on your server

Search Google for 'robots.txt file' for more details (such as blocking certain pages, or even certain bots)

Or use NOINDEX in the meta tag

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

Since the site has been indexed, you may need to request they un-index the pages: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/164734?hl=en

So, in notepad add the following

```
User-agent: * 
Disallow: test.puttinout.com
```

Name it robots.txt and upload it to your root directory.

---

The problem with the above is, it only works for engines that obey the robots file. So, another way, is if you have a static IP address. Simply forward all connections to your website (other than your IP address) away from your testing pages.

---

Another option, is to force a login on your testing. This could even be a javascript password since it doesn't have to be secure. Then, after logged in, authenticate the user with a cookie or similar.

Comment: Thanks @Dave rook will you please guide me what should i add in robots.txt file for block this ?

Comment: Please tell me how to add test.puttinout.com in robots.txt file like ?

User-agent: *
Disallow: test.puttinout.com

Comment: See the SuperUser website for example http://superuser.com/robots.txt